# How to filter from a list of dictionaries and write to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, file-handling

I want some more improvements to my previous question:
[How to format the dictionary object in the list of dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69624786/how-to-format-the-dictionary-object-in-the-list-of-dictionaries)

print(tag_list)

```
[[{'script': [{'domain': 'random.com', 'path': 'js/custom.js'}]},
 {'script': [{'domain': 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
              'path': '/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js'}]},
 {'link': [{'domain': 'random.com', 'path': 'css/bootstrap.min.css'}]},
 {'link': [{'domain': 'random.com', 'path': 'css/style.css'}]},
 {'link': [{'domain': 'random.com', 'path': 'css/responsive.css'}]},
 {'link': [{'domain': 'random.com',
            'path': 'css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css'}]},
 {'link': [{'domain': 'netdna.bootstrapcdn.com',
            'path': '/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css'}]}]]
```

I want to get all the data that is inside the `'domain'` key and store them in a new file `domain.txt` line by line.

domain.txt

```
random.com
cdnjs.cloudfare.com
netdna.bootstrapcdn.com
```

The repetition should be avoided.

Comment: If there is any attempt you have made , it will be good to add that to the question. Others can guide you where you are going wrong

Comment: It may be question for your other post/question, but why the value is single-item list and not simply the `dict` that is inside that list? And why the overall container is list of list of dicts. The solution provided in your other post `output` is list of dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does rather look as though the abundance of inner lists is unnecessary but in case you really need them then this should handle all eventualities:

```
taglist = [[{'script': [{'domain': 'random.com', 'path': 'js/custom.js'}]},
 {'script': [{'domain': 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
              'path': '/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js'}]},
 {'link': [{'domain': 'random.com', 'path': 'css/bootstrap.min.css'}]},
 {'link': [{'domain': 'random.com', 'path': 'css/style.css'}]},
 {'link': [{'domain': 'random.com', 'path': 'css/responsive.css'}]},
 {'link': [{'domain': 'random.com',
            'path': 'css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css'}]},
 {'link': [{'domain': 'netdna.bootstrapcdn.com',
            'path': '/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css'}]}]]
D = set()
with open('domain.txt', 'w') as dfile:
    for tag in taglist:
        for subtag in tag:
            if (d := subtag.get('script', None)) is None:
                if (d := subtag.get('link', None)) is None:
                    continue
            for e in d:
                if (domain := e.get('domain', None)):
                    D.add(domain)
    for domain in D:
        print(domain, file=dfile)
```

[ Note: You'll need Python 3.8+ for this ]

Answer (score 2):

One approach:

```
data = [[{'script': [{'domain': 'random.com', 'path': 'js/custom.js'}]},
         {'script': [{'domain': 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
                      'path': '/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js'}]},
         {'link': [{'domain': 'random.com', 'path': 'css/bootstrap.min.css'}]},
         {'link': [{'domain': 'random.com', 'path': 'css/style.css'}]},
         {'link': [{'domain': 'random.com', 'path': 'css/responsive.css'}]},
         {'link': [{'domain': 'random.com',
                    'path': 'css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css'}]},
         {'link': [{'domain': 'netdna.bootstrapcdn.com',
                    'path': '/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css'}]}]]

# open file for writing
with open("domain.txt", "w") as outfile:
    # create a set to check for duplicates
    seen = set()
    for top in data:
        for e in top:

            # get domain data either from script or link
            se = e.get("script") or e.get("link")

            # fetch the domain name
            domain = se[0]["domain"]

            # write if not previously seen
            if domain not in seen:
                seen.add(domain)
                outfile.write(f"{domain}\n")
```

**Output**

```
random.com
cdnjs.cloudflare.com
netdna.bootstrapcdn.com
```

Comment: If there are more items in the list,